# In Java how can a String that contain an array be transform to an actual Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

Im developing for Android in Java, and using a HttpUrlConnection to connect to an API and get a response.
The response I get is String that contains and array like this:

```
    [{"_id":"1","user":{"_id":"a","displayName":"usuario"},"nombre":"DuckGo","url":"http://www.duckgo.com","created":"2014-12-25T21:30:42.546Z","veces_usado":0,"icono":"","__v":0},
{"_id":"2","user":{"_id":"b","displayName":"usuario"},"nombre":"Wolfram","url":"http://www.wolfram.com","created":"2014-12-25T21:30:00.775Z","veces_usado":0,"icono":"","__v":0}]
```

From what I've read I know a String that contains a JSON can be made an actual JSON with:

```
JSONObject jsonObjecto= new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

How can I do that but with an Array?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the root JSON object is an array in your case, you would parse your input using `JSONArray`

```
try {
    JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(inputJSON);
    JSONObject firstJSONObj = rootArray.getJSONObject(0);
    System.out.println(
        firstJSONObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("displayName") // prints "usuario"
    );
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Check out the [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) docs for more info about the methods available to you.

Answer (score 1):

The same as with `JSONObject` except that you say:

```
new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How is this not an answer to "How can I do that but with an Array?" ? (Since this explains how to do this with an array)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the json-simple API. You can use it to pick apart an entire JSON string however you like.

https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Android also has the capability to parse JSON on its own. Which is a little bit similar to json-simple.

Once it's parsed to your liking you can create an array of strings, iterate through the JSON and store the parsed string values.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your post. you need to convert `json` string to `java bean object`. If it is correct than you can use simply [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library, that will convert json string to java object, using method like,

```
BeanObj beanObj=gson.fromJson(jsonString, BeanObj.class);
```